# Visual Studio 2010 multiple cpp files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, file

I'm pretty new to Visual Studio and I'm currently working on a project in which I want to use multiple .cpp files. Basically I want to make a function outside main.cpp in function.cpp and that function should be able to change global variables. Then I'd use that function in main.cpp.

I tried making a header named globals.h and putting static variables in it. I included globals.h in both main and function.cpp and it compiled but whenever I call that function in main it does absolutely nothing.
When I try to include function.cpp in main.cpp I get multiple definition error while compiling.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you show some code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `static` variables in header files. As headers are “incorporated” in compilation units, all variables declared as `static` in your header become scoped inside your compilation unit only. You won't be able to use the same global variable in your cpp files.

This is how your structure should be:

```
globals.h
------
extern int my_global_integer;


main.cpp
------
#include "globals.h"

// here use my_global_integer;

function.cpp
------
#include "globals.h"

// global variables have to be declared in exactly one compilation unit.
// otherwise the linker will complain that the variable is defined twice.
int my_global_integer = 0;
```

Comment: Did everything you said and it's working now, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

What did u mean by "trying to include function.cpp in main.cpp"? Are u trying to use the function.cpp's functions in main.cpp? In that case all u need to do is to include function.h in ur main.cpp file.

As for the error part, make sure u've provided the prototypes and data variables of header file within #ifndef and #endif syntax.That should solve the multiple definition error.

Your function.h should look like,

#ifndef FUNCTION_H

#define FUNCTION_H

//variables declaration and prototype declaration goes here

#endif

Comment: Please explain how you can type long words such as "prototypes" and "multiple definition", but you can't type a small word such as "you".  I'm curious because many people do this.